# how to refresh data in modal1 after modal 2 save

Tags: json, codeigniter

First, I have a list table in each row have button edit, if button edit click show modal1 where have detail from each row and have button to edit2, if button edit2 click will show modal2 after button save from modal2 been click how to refresh data in modal1

So far where all modal been close and modal1 open data have correct update, but I want just modal2 close and data in modal1 refresh without close all modal

This is my button save code function `save1()`

```
{
    $('#btnSave1').text('saving...'); //change button text
    $('#btnSave1').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
    var url;

    if(save1_method == 'add1') {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_add1')?>";
    } else {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_update1')?>";
    }

    // ajax adding data to database
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            {
                $('#modal_form3').modal('hide');  
             //   $('#modal_form3').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {     
             //     window.alert('hidden event resfreh!');
             //   });
                reload_table();
            }

            $('#btnSave1').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave1').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
            $('#btnSave1').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave1').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

        }
    });
}
```